# android: layout just like tiger machine

Tags: android, layout

I would like to make a layout such that when pressing the below 4 buttons, the above 3 buttons will keep on shifting 1 button width to the left (ie, when pressing one button at bottom it will show the next full button 3 in the middle...need some kind of animation?)

Put it simple, I would like to make a layout similar to the tiger gambling machine, but instead of each slot rotating upwards or downwards, it would be great the entire row move left for one slot if press any bottom buttons once.

However, the layout codes make me headache. How could I make it such that it can be the middle button to occupy the middle, and with left button and right button just showing half as shown in the second pic?

## Current Layout

[image: situation now]

## Desired layout

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"  
    android:background="@drawable/blackboard2">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_span="6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Abc"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Q1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"          
        android:background="@drawable/grey_sq_btn"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Q2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"         
        android:background="@drawable/grey_sq_btn"            
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Q3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp""            
        android:background="@drawable/grey_sq_btn"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="15dp" />           

</TableRow>     

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_sq_btn"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_sq_btn"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_sq_btn"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_sq_btn"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

</TableRow>
```

Comment: You can't use a `TableLayout`/`TableRow` if you plan to show only a part of some views? Do you want to animate the new views that should appear?

Comment: yup, but i am new to that animation programming..would there be any examples? many thanks!!